# How Do I Resolve android.arch.lifecycle:common Version Conflicts?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components

Given a project with this set of dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0"
  compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0"
  compile "com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0"
  compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.3'
  compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
  compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0'
  compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta2'
  compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:1.0.0-beta2'
  compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-beta2"
  compile "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-beta2"
  annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-beta2"
  androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0"
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
  androidTestCompile 'android.arch.core:core-testing:1.0.0-beta2'
  androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0"
  androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0"
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Error:Conflict with dependency 'android.arch.lifecycle:common' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (1.0.2) and test app (1.0.0) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifact dependency inconsistencies are a common problem, and I expect this to be a frequent issue with the Architecture Components, given that the versioning of those components is byzantine<sup>1</sup>.

In this case, there is an undocumented version `1.0.2` of the undocumented `android.arch.lifecycle:common` artifact.

`android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-beta2` and `android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:1.0.0-beta2` depend upon this undocumented version `1.0.2` of the undocumented `android.arch.lifecycle:common` artifact. However, the corresponding test artifact (`android.arch.core:core-testing:1.0.0-beta2`) depends on version `1.0.0` of `android.arch.lifecycle:common`. As a result, we get the conflict.

The workaround is to manually request `1.0.2` for the test code, via:

```
androidTestCompile 'android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.2'
```

Gradle will now use 1.0.2 for both the main code and the test code, and all is well.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> [The term "byzantine"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Byzantine) is used to describe something that is unnecessarily complex. [The Byzantines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_Greeks) might have described complex things with the phrase "like the versioning system of the Architecture Components", had those components existed back then.</sub>

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal: Feel free to ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you provide a [mcve] and explain your issue.